# How to create a string of column names from rows which are not NaNs in python?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have the following dataset:

```
data = {
    'A': [1, np.nan, np.nan],
    'B': [2, np.nan, np.nan],
    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a comma-separated string from column names where values are not NaNs. So the outcome would be:

```
outcome = {
    'A': [1, np.nan, np.nan],
    'B': [2, np.nan, np.nan],
    'C': [np.nan, np.nan, 6],
    'string': ['A,B', '', 'C']
}
```

I found this solution but don't know how to apply to my case.

```
df0['colX'] = df0.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(c for c in df0.columns if x[c] != 0), axis=1).replace('', 0)
```

Comment: There are no NaNs in your data. Did you mean `0`?

Comment: `df["string"] = (df.notnull() @ (df.columns+",")).str[:-1]`

Comment: @Barmar sorry I meant NaNs